# how to get node graph like rqt_graph with command line?

Tags: ros2, rqt-graph

my `ros2` env does not have a display or visualization config, is there a method only by `cli` to get the `node graph`? (e.g. save in `*.png`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into this recently and came across https://github.com/kiwicampus/ros2_graph. This allows you to generate a ROS graph in Mermaid (a markdown language) on the CLI which can then be converted to an image either on another machine or on the CLI and then `scp`'d to another machine. Hope this helps.